# PHP RegEx remove characters between specific characters

Tags: php, regex

I've done some digging around and can't seem to find an exact answer to this question.  I've tried online regex testers to no avail.  I am trying to remove text from a string between 2 points.

Here is an example of the string:

```
##- Please type your reply above this line -## Awesome service Message-Id:5HKR22W0_53adb264b3dc5_63f13f80dc4b33f824958ec_sprut - 3 days ago
```

I would like to trim the string to say only `Awesome service`.

So, I need to remove the `##` and everything in between, as well as `Message-ID` through `sprut`.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:  Just to be clear, i am trying to squeeze this into a php expression.  This is what i have that is not working:

```
<?php 

if(preg_match('##(.*?)##\\s*(.+?)\\s*Message-Id:.*$',$tweet['tweet'],$matches)) $tweet['tweet'] = $matches[1];
echo (string) trim($tweet["tweet"]);

?>
```

Comment: Why are we not seeing your attempts to solve this?

Comment: <?php 

if(preg_match('##(.*?)##\\s*(.+?)\\s*Message-Id:.*$',$tweet['tweet'],$matches)) $tweet['tweet'] = $matches[1];
echo (string) trim($tweet["tweet"]);

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a positive lookaheads and lookbehinds to extract the string `Awesome Service` which was in between `##` and `Message-ID`.

```
<?php
$mystring = "##- Please type your reply above this line -## Awesome service Message-Id:5HKR22W0_53adb264b3dc5_63f13f80dc4b33f824958ec_sprut - 3 days ago";
$regex = '~.*(?<=##\s)(.*)(?= Message-Id:).*~';
$replacement = "$1";
echo preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $mystring);
?> //=> Awesome service
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/eU3rG4/7)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily match portion between `##` and `##` using `##(.*?)##`. Also removing everything after message id is trivial: `Message-Id:.*`. Joined together you have: `~##(.*?)##\\s*(.+?)\\s*Message-Id:.*$~` and you can easily use one of these:

```
$regex = '~##(.*?)##\\s*(.+?)\\s*Message-Id:.*$~';

// Use replace
$data = preg_replace( $regex, '$2', $data);

// Or match
$matches = array();
if( preg_match($regex, $data, $matches)){
    $data = $matches[2];
}
```

Life example [here](http://ideone.com/c3DspG).

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("!## (.+) Message.+ - (.+)!", $your_text, $taken)
```

accesing to the catched words if they are 'isset' $taken[1] and $taken[2]

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$re = "/##.*?## *| Message-Id:.*$/"; 
$str = "##- Please type your reply above this line -## Awesome service Message-Id:5HKR22W0_53adb264b3dc5_63f13f80dc4b33f824958ec_sprut - 3 days ago"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, '', $str); // Awesome service
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xI5mX6/1)